# Jeddah - Costa Rica then return via Costa Rica - Madrid - Jeddah, will I need a visa for Spain?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, madrid, mad

I am a Filipino citizen in Jeddah, Saudi Arabia, and booked for a holiday trip to Costa Rica.

My flight is

- Jeddah -> Madrid via Saudi Airlines
- 24 hour layover
- Madrid -> SJO (Costa Rica) via Iberia

My return trip is
 - SJO (Costa Rica) -> Madrid via Iberia
 - layover
 - Madric -> Jeddah via Saudi Airlines

I will be entering and leaving Madrid twice during the round trip flights.

I  would like to know what type of Schengen visa is appropriate to apply for me to pass Madrid twice with out any hassles in Madrid airport immigration?

Comment: If you don't leave the airport international zone you don't need any VISA... except in USA, but that's not your case

Comment: Is your transit exactly 24 hours?
You do not need a visa for a transit. But if you wish to enter the Spain, you will need a visa. I would encourage you obtain a visa, because no one wants to spend 24 hours in an airport, and the airline authorities may disbelieve that you intend to do that.

Comment: @Ivan the transit without visa rules are more complicated than that. Many countries do require visas for certain citizens even remaining in the international area of the airport.

Comment: It's good to know that @Calchas. Except USA ESTA, I've never need to obtain a VISA or similar to transit in any country. I'll try to get more info about this in my next trips.